# how to display a popup windows with transparent background image?

Tags: android

[image]

Hello guys , i am making a application in which I display pop up-windows with background image,

the background image i set to the popup window is transparent image
but the problem is that when the popup window is displayed the background image is not displayed properly....

although it is a transparent image it displays the black strip around the corner of image..

can anybody help me out ??

PopupDemoActivity.java

> package com.demo.popupwindow.;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;  
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class PopupDemoActivity extends Activity {

Button searchMenu, viewOrder;

PopupWindow popUp;
LayoutParams params;
FrameLayout layout;
// LinearLayout layout;
boolean click = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popdemodemo);

    searchMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    viewOrder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order);
    popUp = new PopupWindow(this);

    // layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout = new FrameLayout(this);


    viewOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (click) {
                popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT,
                        0, 0);
                popUp.update(30, 75, 500, 400);
                click = false;
            } else {
                popUp.dismiss();
                click = true;
            }

        }
    });

    // popUp.setContentView(layout);

    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.order_back);
    // layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    popUp.setContentView(layout);
}

}
```

popupdemo.xml

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white_color"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_lay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="Search Menu"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/order"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text="View Order"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout file of your popup view please.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Jayesh, try this :

```
popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
            android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution as it's not prohibiting the popup from dismissing on outside click

Comment: Have you tried this "popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true/false);" ?

Answer (score 11):

set

```
popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

It should do the work. what you are getting in background is some sort of background content of popup Window

Comment: What you do is create a transparent png (eg. clear.png) file and place it in your drawables folder, then call popUp.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.clear);

Answer (score 1):

In your XML you are defining the background of your popup as

> android:background="@color/white_color"

Try applying background image here rather than on run time.

> android:background="@drawable/order_back"

OR

move the popup layout changing code above (before  `popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT,0, 0);`)

Comment: thanks for answer, but I need the background image for popup window not for the layout that i set for the PopDemoActivity as a setContentView(); and I am not changing the layout but for displaying the popup window i am creating new layout and set the background... I am not using the existing background.....

Comment: @Jayesh did you figure out the solution ?

Comment: @rana: see vijju's answer